# How to calculate E(x^2) in order to find variance

Tags: statistics

Lets say that we are trying to find the variance of a coin with a $0.6$ probability of heads flipped $n$ times.
(Binomial with $p=0.6$)

Given that the equation to find variance is $E(n^2)-E(n)^2$ and that $E(n) = 0.6n$:

How are you supposed to find the $E(n^2)$?  I tried simply squaring the $n$, resulting in $0.6n^2$ but it does not give me the correct answer when calculating the variance: $0.6n^2-0.36n^2=0.24n^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the flips are independent, so $1$-if-heads-$0$-if-tails are $n$ independent variables across the flips. If you calculate the variance for one flip, the variance for $n$ flips is $n$ times this by additivity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The variance of a binomial distribution is
$$\mathrm{Var}(X)=np(1-p)$$